# Scopes of the system in system analysis

Tags: terminology, system-analysis

Maybe someone knows, what does it mean "scopes of the system" (or something like that) in system analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect to ever hear anyone speak of the "scopes" of a system.  The "scope" of a system is the set of functionality it's meant to encompass.

Answer (score 1):

The scope (in singular) is the functionality the system will provide to the users. It defines what the system will do and what the system won't do.

Answer (score 0):

The Scope of a system is the functionality which it encompasses. On the other hand, things which are not relevant are outside the scope of the system.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a system includes the modules you are intending to build. stuff that is outside of the scope will usually be a sub system you will not be developing .

Example : if I am building a website that shows information on restaurants. The data on restaurant is in the scope, the map showing the restaurant location is outside of the scope!
i would suggest using google or bing maps (API) and not developing this module yourself.